# how to listen for submit event.

Tags: jquery, events, asynchronous, polling

Hi i want to know how to tell if a event was fire within 2.5 seconds.

here is external function written by some other developer.

```
function validateAndSubmit() { 
    if (validateRule(document.getElementById("inputElem").value) {
        document.form.submit;
    } else {
        alert ("Value is wrong");
    }
} 

<input type="button" onclick="validateAndSubmit();" id="updatePage"/>
```

I have a jquery listener.

```
 $("#updatePage").click(function() {
      popupWaitingDialog();
      setTimeout(function() {
            // insert code to see if submit was fire causing page to load or unload. 
            hideWaitingDialog();
      }, 2500); 
 });
```

I have a waiting dialog that shows up, if the validation fail, I want to be able to hide it. The only way i know if the validation fail is if submit or reload event is fire.

Comment: Display the waiting dialogue in `validateAndSubmit()` before calling `document.form.submit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the popup to the submission function:

```
function validateAndSubmit() { 
    if (validateRule(document.getElementById("inputElem").value) {
        popup WaitingDialog();
        document.form.submit();
    } else {
        alert ("Value is wrong");
    }
}
```

You can then remove the `click` handler. Alternatively, you could keep the `click` handler and add the validation code check there:

```
$("#updatePage").click(function() {
    popupWaitingDialog();
    validateAndSubmit(); // Doesn't return unless validation fails
    hideWaitingDialog();
});
```

Comment: thanks but the validateAndSubmit is external function in another web application. This means i have no right to change it.It is an embedded iframe application.

Comment: I've added a version that calls validateAndSubmit without changing it.

Comment: Thanks since it was iframe i had to access the function via $(#iframe)[0].contentWindow.validateAndSubmit();